# My animation didn't migrate well to Blender 2.9

Tags: animation, modifiers, physics

I have this animation of spheres inflating that I made in Blender 2.79, which looks like this:

[image]

*Spheres inflate as they fall*

When I open it with 2.9, this is what the animation looks like:

[image]

*Balls move up and down but don't fall and mostly hover*

**How can I repair this animation in 2.9 (or higher)?**

PS: I cannot upload to blend-exchange because of a "*All uploaded files must be in the blend file format*" error.

[Blend file.](https://pasteall.org/media/f/e/fed273147dd5f4135415c7f2f277b434.blend)

Comment: You can upload to https://pasteall.org/blend/ if Blend-Exchange doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnEason Thanks John! I've added them file.

Comment: Ok. Hopefully someone who knows more about changes between the Blender versions than I do can have a look at your file and see what's going on!

Comment: This is a softbody simulation... have you simply tried deleting the bake and rebaking the simulation? In my Blender version 3.1 it works as your old version.